# How do I make PyCharm recognize placeholders in SQL statements?

Tags: pycharm, code-inspection

I'm using PyCharm and I have an error on this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= %(id)s
```

The code syntax inspection says:

```
<expression> expected, got '%'
```

Is there a way to disable this error message? In other words, how do I make PyCharm recognize placeholders in SQL statements?

**Edit**

Here is my solution:

For `%(id)s` and `%s` you have to had `%\((\w+)\)s` and `%s` in `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | User parameters` and select `All languages` not only SQL

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | User parameters` -- you can add custom parameter pattern there. Also make sure that appropriate `Enable ...` options are enabled.

Comment: Thanks !
I tried this pattern but it doesn't work : `\%\(([^$\(\)]*)\)\s`
Do you have an idea please?

Comment: I think those brackets `()` in actual placeholder `%(id)s` are what making it break. I've tried few things and none of them worked. Right now I may only suggest to submit official support ticket at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: `%\(([^\$\(\)]*)\)s` does work in the one test case I've tried so far.  Most of my code base uses `%s` so I've also added that as a pattern.

Answer (score 23):

Is this SQL in a SQL console, or in a string in a Python script? I had this same issue and solved it by checking the box above the list of patterns, labeled "Enable in string literals with SQL injection". If you're doing this in a SQL console window, check the first box.

As @LazyOne notes, go to `Settings/Preferences > Tools > Database > User Parameters` and you'll see two checkboxes at the top:
`Enable in console and SQL files`
`Enable in string literals with SQL injection`

While you can add your own custom patters, I believe the pattern that matches this parameter syntax (for me, parameters for psycopg2 for use in Postgres) is out-of-the-box in Pycharm, the last one in the list.

See here for reference:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/user-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Nate's answer (built-in regex `%\((\w+)\)s` works for PostgreSQL), i've managed to get this work only **via reordering the patterns and moving target regex to the top of the list**.

One could also try to disable other rules and see if that helps.