# Django cursor.executemany parameters

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django cursor.execuremany for a while now and I wanted to do some cleading up.

On this Stackoverflow page I read that it is a bad idea to use the string formatting operator, and use a questionmark. 
[How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

However when I use this in my program I get an error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
from django.db import connection

values = ((1, "john"), (2, "robert"), (3, "angela"))

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "REPLACE INTO names (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)"
cursor.executemany(query, values)
```

When I only replace the `?` with `%s` it works as expected.

Another thing (that got me started searching) is that PyCharm is giving me an error when using `%s`.

```
<expression> expedted, got %
```

This is not the main issue, but I'm not sure if this could make a difference.

What I am using

- Python 2.7
- Django 1.4
- MySql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I only replace the ? with %s it works as expected.

The `?` placeholder is used for [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) only:

> Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as `%s` or `:1`.)

MySQL drivers expect to see `%s` as a query parameter placeholder:

```
query = "REPLACE INTO names (id, name) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.executemany(query, values)
```

---

> Another thing (that got me started searching) is that PyCharm is giving me an error when using %s.

PyCharm does not issue any warnings on my end. You've probably did something different:

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to get things cleaned up since PyCharm is giving an error when using the `%s` placeholder

Comment: @JohanVergeer yeah, sure, getting to that. Thanks.

Comment: @JohanVergeer okay, updated with what is happening on my end. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was finally able to get rid of the error. Thanks to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082943/sql-inspection-in-pycharm